# PostgREST POST method converts Array of ints to text

Tags: postgresql, postgrest

I have a PostgreSQL function `logschema.movement` that returns a subset of the table `logschema.movement`, the function looks like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION logschema.movement(
    "ids" bigint[], "date" TEXT)
    RETURNS SETOF logschema.movement
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    
AS $$ 
BEGIN
RETURN  QUERY (SELECT * FROM logschema.movement WHERE "ids" = ANY ("ids") AND "day" >= $2::TIMESTAMP);
END;
$$;
```

This function works within PostgreSQL, e.g. `SELECT logschema.movement(ARRAY[1,2,3], '2021-09-09')` doesn't return an error.
If I try to query the function with PostgREST and axios like this:

```js
let payload = {ids: [1,2,3], date: "2021-09-08"}
return await RequestService.postData(new URL(this.api + `/rpc/movement`, this.urlBase), payload);
```

I get a long error message which contains:

```
...
data:
      { hint:
         'No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.',
        details: null,
        code: '42883',
        message:
         'function logschema.movement(lastBatteryChangeDate => text, pseudoIds => text) does not exist' } }
...
```

It looks to me like my array got converted to a string but I'm not sure.

My PostgreSQL Version is `PostgreSQL 12.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424) 10.3.1 20210424, 64-bit` and my PostgREST Version is `v7.0.1`

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I understand that you pass your input parameters through the URL, so yes they may be converted into text. You can update your logschema.movement function by declaring ids as a text and then convert it in the function as a bigint[] : `ANY ("ids" :: bigint[])`

Comment: That worked, thanks alot, totally forgot that you can just convert cast to arrays not only to primitives